# Use of setjmp and longjmp in single-threaded MPI applications

Tags: multithreading, mpi, setjmp

I have read other questions posted by other users regarding setjmp and longjmp in multithreaded applications. People say that the use of these two may not be safe with multithreading.

So is it safe to use setjmp and longjmp in single-threaded MPI applications where I  have only the main thread?

I am asking this because I know that MPI runtime creates some other implementation-dependent threads that are running along side with my main() thread so I am not sure whether this will affect the use of setjmp and longjmp in my MPI application or not.

Comment: setjmp/longjmp are thread-safe (as long as you don't setjmp from one thread and longjmp to its context from another).

Comment: @Sneftel, ok I see. Those questions are about performing long jumps across different threads...that's why it is said to be unsafe. Thanks.